# Matrix Multiplication within ParLapply or foreach in R

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing

I have a question about doing matrix multiplication with the parallel package in R.

I encountered a wired situation that the matrix multiplication, 500*5 times 5*5, idled when running it on a cluster. I think the code itself is correct based on the fact that it ran successfully on my own computer.

I really can't think any reason why this is happening. Thanks ahead if anyone can explain this. Let me know if you need more information.

Here is the code

```
library(doParallel)

medForest <- function(
  x.b, x.e, treat, y.b, y.e, ntree, nCore=detectCores()-1
  ) {
  cl <- makeCluster(nCore,type="FORK",outfile="debug.txt")
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  forest <- foreach(i = 1:ntree, .combine = list, .multicombine = TRUE)  %dopar%  
          {
              tree <- UniAssoc(x.b = x.b, x.e = x.e, treat = treat,
                               y.b = y.b, y.e = y.e)
              return(tree)
          }
  stopImplicitCluster()
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(forest)
}

UniAssoc <- function(x.b, x.e, treat, y.b, y.e,) {
  diff.x <- x.e[,,drop=FALSE] - x.b[,,drop=FALSE]
  diff.y <- y.e - y.b

  CCA.result <- cancor(scale(diff.x),scale(diff.y))

  # Not error but idle forever
  # diff.y is 500*5 matrix, CCA.result$ycoef is 5*5 matrix
  direction <- scale(diff.y)%*%CCA.result$ycoef

  # Will run if diff.y is reduced to a 450*5 matrix
  # No idle
  #direction <- scale(diff.y)%*%CCA.result$ycoef
  return(direction)
}
```

My question is why the first matrix multiplication will idle forever on a campus cluster. It is not a legitimate behavior. And I am looking what can be the cause for this situation intuitively.

Comment: welcome on stackoverflow. Can you provide some data which make your problem understand. and describe your expected output.

Comment: @and: Thanks for your comment. I just updated my question and added a short version of the code. I am looking for an intuitive idea that what may be the causes for this.

Comment: thats looks already better...but there are still somethings to do for a good MCVE. 1) make it not more complected than necessary; for example in the fourth line you load `source("UniAssocTree.R")` what is it? is it the same script which you introducing below as `UniAssoc.R`. if so delete the fourth line and add the function you need between the package and the first function. 2) in the first line of `UniAssco` function there is one comma to many: `UniAssoc <- function(x.b, x.e, treat, y.b, y.e) {` 3) use some dummy data to illustrate your problem. for example you can use the `runif()` function

Comment: 4) are you sure you need all this function and packages to explain your problem? extract the part of your code which cause the problem. people prefer to don't install useless packages and search problems in complex nested functions. if the complexity is the problem, make us clear that examples that the single part work fine. good luck :)

Comment: @and: Thanks for your advice. I just edit my post a little bit to accommodate your suggestions. However, I still can't provide dummy data examples in this case, since they worked. I am sure it is not a problem with the format/class of data since I have explicitly checked. Fortunately, I get over this problem by using `cl <- makeCluster(nCore)` instead of `cl <- makeCluster(nCore,type="FORK",outfile="debug.txt")` as in the original post. I highly doubt there is something incomplete about the forking mechanism, which leads to the idle when computing "large" matrix multiplication.

Comment: FYI, I am working on a Linux cluster, so the forking was supposed to work. The reason why I originally used `cl <- makeCluster(nCore,type="FORK",outfile="debug.txt")` is because I want to use `ParLapply` function. Obviously, it failed, and I switch to `foreach %dopar%`. But I keep the fork part when making clusters, since I thought it would automatically fork the variables, a lot of, in the global environment based on my readings. It turned out it brought me a lot of troubles.